# Authenticate application using another token from another application

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, hybrid-mobile-app, multi-device-hybrid-apps

Here is my issue , I have two hybrid apps , App #1 ,and App #2 , if I login with App #1 , and want App#2 to use same token for authentication without need for user to enter his/her credentials again , what should be best solution for that ?

Comment: I haven't used it, but in android you can have a sharedUserID. You put this ID in the manifest of every app and then they can share datas. I have no idea how to implement this in cordova, but may be the right way.